# How to restore a specific activity that is not the launcher activity and instantly navigate to it after the system has killed the app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have multiple activities in my app and a specific problem in which after my app is killed by the system, upon reopening the app (icon or from the overview) it starts loading my launcher activity with the splash screen instead of loading the last activity that the app was using.

My launcher activity is essentially a form of a login screen which should be used only the first time the app is opened, but instead it is reopened every time the app is killed by the system and app reopened by the user.

I am inexperienced and do not know if this is the default behavior of Android or a bug, I have searched through stack overflow but could not find a conclusive answer.

Coincidentally this well known long standing Android bug has appeared. (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36941942)

I do not know if the two problems might coincide, and I cannot be sure when the longstanding bug has first appeared because previously I was testing through Instant Run which does not result in the bug, but am now forced to test through play because it does result in the bug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I am inexperienced and do not know if this is the default behavior of Android or a bug

This is the default behavior of Android, if there is no current task associated with your app. That includes:

- User swiping the task off of the overview screen
- You terminating the process and task from inside Android Studio
- All the time if the user has been out of the app for 30+ minutes
- User using Force Stop on your app in Settings
- And probably some other scenarios that I'm not thinking of right now

> My launcher activity is essentially a form of a login screen which should be used only the first time the app is opened

I recommend that your launcher `<intent-filter>` be on your primary activity in the app. If that activity determines that the user has not logged in, it can do something to authenticate the user (display a fragment, start an activity, etc.).

Comment: To add to this, I usually do this kind of check in the onStart() method.  This way even if the user just minimises the app and for whatever reason the stored credentials fail in the interim (e.g. expired auth token), resuming the app will trigger the check to redirect to the login activity or switch the current fragment to the login fragment.